# Cool TagCloud for jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tag-cloud

I am looking for a cool plugin for tag clouds. 
Somewhat similar to this [rotating tag-cloud](http://www.roytanck.com/tag-cloud/).

Is there any that you can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CumulusTags

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/StringBall

http://www.jeroenvanwarmerdam.nl/content/resources/javascript/jscumulus/js-cumulus.html

mootools one:
http://student.agh.edu.pl/~fatyga/repos/stratus/example.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more projects around realizing a cumulus on JavaScript. The most links above do not work, but google helped out.

http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php

https://github.com/ernesto-sun/rotator-js

The latter is developed by me, more project-links in the README at github. I need more reputation to post more links at stackoverflow :)

Hope that helps.